# is there a web analytics framework?

Tags: analytics, ssas

is there a free framework which I can use to develop a web analytics tool?

We want to know how many people visit our site, which pages of our sites is the Most Popular and etc.

like this:
http://www.google.com/intl/en/analytics/tour.html

Obviously, we do not need to analytize other sites but only our own site.

BTW, we use tomcat as the servlet container.

---

Does these analytics tool work based on the server log?

Comment: What is wrong with google analytics?

Comment: Use a thrid-part tool may be limited. For example, how about if google can not be avaible ? (I am a Chinese guy)

Comment: Piwik (posted below) works similar to GA using a JavaScript tracking tag. If you just want to parse server logs you can use awstats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not based on Java/Servlets, but if you can run PHP on your Tomcat you might want to have a look at [Piwik](http://piwik.org) ([Demo](http://demo.piwik.org)) which can be customized using plugins. Their plugin architecture is quite good and well [documented](http://dev.piwik.org/trac/wiki/Plugins/HowToWritePluginIntroduction).

Answer (score 4):

[Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com) is a full featured web analytics framework written in PHP. You interface with it via javascript, php or REST calls.

Answer (score 0):

[Qmonix](http://qmonix.com) is basically what you are looking for. It's analytics SDK that provides server software to install it on your machine. So you control where it is and how it's accessible (e.g. using your firewall). And there are no third-party services like Google involved.